# What is the history behind `ulimit -m` / RLIMIT_RSS not working?

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory, ulimit

According to `man setrlimit` (which is what `man ulimit` directs me to),

> RLIMIT_RSS
>
> Specifies the limit (in bytes) of the process's resident set (the number of virtual pages resident in RAM).  This limit  has 
>   effect  only  in  Linux
>      2.4.x, x < 30, and there affects only calls to madvise(2) specifying MADV_WILLNEED.

So it seems that `ulimit` (and `setrlimit`) can only restrict the virtual memory used by a process.  On the other hand, answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/561450/377022) assert (rightly, it seems) that virtual memory is an almost meaningless statistic, especially in, e.g., Java applications where it is typical to request far more virtual memory than will be used.

So I'm wondering about the history of this seeming disconnect between what limits I can impose on the system and what numbers are actually meaningful.  Insofar as it can be answered, why is this the present state of things?

Answer (score 0):

RSS is an implementation detail. The only resources that your program can control are RLIMIT_AS and RLIMIT_DATA. A Unix implementation could fix RSS == VMA always (commit all memory requested) and all Java virtual machines would crash while loading whenever the computer is not beefy enough to be prepared to have its memory wasted.

So, the comments on the referenced thread are just that person's opinion and they do not match with the architecture of Unix.

To try this behavior on linux:

1. boot kernel with mem=4G parameter (or try with different values)
2. sudo sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=2
3. run Chromium or some program that tries to reserve more than 4 GB (crash)